# Drag from treeview to picture box and connect elements

Tags: c#

I'm stuck with this problem. I have in one frame pictureBox and treeview. I want to drag and drop from treeview to picture box and in that picture box I paint another picture (first picture box is map in treeview i have 'Sings')

```
private void pictureBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     Type testTip = new TreeNode().GetType();
     TreeNode dragedNode;
     _mouseDownSelectionWindow= Rectangle.Empty;

     if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(testTip))
     {
         dragedNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData(testTip);

         PictureBox picOneFaceUpA = new PictureBox();
         picOneFaceUpA.Parent = MapView;
         picOneFaceUpA.Tag = dragedNode;
         TreeNode tr = (TreeNode)picOneFaceUpA.Tag;
         Sing vr = (Sing)tr.Tag;
         picOneFaceUpA.Name = vr.idSing;
         vr.onMap = true;

         int xCord = e.X;
         int yCord = e.Y;
         picOneFaceUpA.Location = MapView.PointToClient(new Point (xCord - 20, yCord - 20));
         picOneFaceUpA.BackgroundImage = vr.image; 
         vr.location = picOneFaceUpA.Location;

         dictionary.Add(picOneFaceUpA.Location, vr);

         picOneFaceUpA.Size = new Size(40, 40);
         picOneFaceUpA.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
         picOneFaceUpA.BringToFront();
         picOneFaceUpA.Focus();
     }

}
```

And that works, but how I can connect so when I click on Sing on map it gets some kind of focus(frame or something) and it selects treenode in treview that I used to make that picture box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have created a connection when you have stored the dragged node in the PictureBox's Tag.

To make it work you need to code a few events for the created `PictureBoxes`.

Here is the minimum:

When clicked I set a `Border`, select the `Treenode` you have already stored in the `Tag` and explicitly set the focus on the `PictureBox`. (PBs don't usually get focus when clicked, so we need to do it in code, so we can catch the `LostFocus` event..)

```
picOneFaceUpA.Click += (ss,ee) => {
    picOneFaceUpA.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    treeView1.SelectedNode = dragedNode;
    picOneFaceUpA.Focus();
};
```

And in the `LostFocus` I simply remove the `Border`:

```
picOneFaceUpA.LostFocus += (ss, ee) =>
{
    picOneFaceUpA.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
};
```

Don't forget to set the treeview `HideSelection = false;` so you can see the selection while the focus still is on the PB!

Now, depending on the images you show, the border may be a bit weak. For a stronger effect you would have to code the `Paint` event to draw something more flashy on the top of the control..:

```
picOneFaceUpA.Paint += (ss, ee) =>
{
    if (picOneFaceUpA.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
        ee.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Orange, 0, 0,
                    picOneFaceUpA.ClientSize.Width - 1, 
                    picOneFaceUpA.ClientSize.Height - 1);
};
```

In your code you use a `picOneFaceUpA.Focus();`call. This seems to clash with setting the `LostFocus` event, so will have to remove it!

Comment: Tnx man, but when i added that code application crashes "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." I added that code in that method....

Comment: That's strange. You should add the code right in the sequence where you set all other properties of the picOneFaceUpA element.

Comment: I did.  i have put it after  `picOneFaceUpA.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch; `

Comment: I have put double click event and its work fine......
`
picOneFaceUpA.MouseDoubleClick += (ss, ee) =>
                {
                    frmCulturalMonument frame = new frmCulturalMonument(picOneFaceUpA.Name);
                    frame.ShowDialog();
                    this.refresh();
                }`

Comment: OK, that sounds good. Are there still issues with the other events? You will need to remove the    `picOneFaceUpA.Focus();`call as it seems to clash with the creation of the `LostFocus`  event! (Yes, I could reproduce __various errors__, depending on where I moved it..I guess a timed version would work, but it is actually necessary?) I have updated my answer..

Comment: One more thing, i have serialisation so i save all dictionarys and it works fine, but when i load, i load everything but pictures on map, for some reason it doesnt work you have idea how to do that. I implemented method that take all elements that are in dictionary of sings on map and do this: `Vrste.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);
                    sVrste.Location = sveMape.mapaSpomenika[key].mapa_lokacija;
                    sVrste.BackgroundImage = sveMape.mapaSpomenika[key].ikonica;
                    sVrste.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                    `

Comment: `Vrste.Tag = sveMape.mapaSpomenika[key];
sVrste.BringToFront();`